# Spring security: Controller method access to certain roles

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have three methods in a controller. But each method has different access roles.

```
@RequestMapping("/deleteMethod.htm")
    public String deleteMethod(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        // Can be accessed by only ROLE_ADMIN
    }

@RequestMapping("/editMethod.htm")
    public String editMethod(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
          // Can be accessed by ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER

    }

    @RequestMapping("/viewMethod.htm")
    public ModelAndView viewMethod(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        // Anyone can access this method
    }
```

I think i am getting confused here in intercepting url .Anyway, i just want to authorize the methods of the controller. Can anyone explain how can this be done?

**security.xml**

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.htm" default-target-url="/welcome.htm"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.htm" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout.htm" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

       users-by-username-query="
          select username,password,enabled 
          from tbl_users where username=?" 

       authorities-by-username-query="
          select u.username, ur.authority from tbl_users u, tbl_user_roles ur 
          where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username =?  " 

    />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be done by using annotations. Enable secured annotations in your configuration.

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

And use `@Secured` annotation over method declarations.

```
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
public String deleteMethod(HttpServletRequest request,
     HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    // Can be accessed by only ROLE_ADMIN
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >

    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/deleteMethod.htm*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/editMethod.htm*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/viewMethod.htm*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <form-login login-page="/login.htm" default-target-url="/welcome.htm"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.htm" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout.htm" />
</http>
```